# How to get rid of the background gradient of the inline GtkToolbar?

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3, pygi, style

When you run the below code, it will show an inline toolbar in a window. Notice how the inline toolbar has a stand-out backbround. Is there a way to apply CSS to get rid of it and make blend with regular window color?

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk

button_names = [Gtk.STOCK_ABOUT, Gtk.STOCK_ADD, Gtk.STOCK_REMOVE, Gtk.STOCK_QUIT]
buttons = [Gtk.ToolButton.new_from_stock(name) for name in button_names]
toolbar = Gtk.Toolbar()
toolbar.set_show_arrow(False)
for button in buttons:
    toolbar.insert(button, -1)
style_context = toolbar.get_style_context()
style_context.add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_INLINE_TOOLBAR)
grid = Gtk.Grid()
grid.add(toolbar)
label = Gtk.Label()
grid.add(label)
window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_size_request(200, 50)
window.add(grid)
window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Using andrewsomething code, it's starting to look better but the "border" is still there and takes up space. Notice in the below screenshot the toolbar on the left is smaller than the regular buttons on the right:
[image: ubiquity testing]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here we go:

[image: example screenshot]

First you need to find the default background color for the the current theme. Then you can inject it into the current css for the GtkToolbar class.

```python
# Get the default window background color for the the current theme.
win_style_context = window.get_style_context()
bg = win_style_context.lookup_color('theme_bg_color')[1].to_string()

# Then we set that as the background for GtkToolbar
# We also make the boarder transparent
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
toolbar_css = ".inline-toolbar.toolbar { background: %s; border-color: transparent; }" % (bg)
css_provider.load_from_data(toolbar_css.encode('UTF-8'))
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
win_style_context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider,
                                          Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

Note that you need to `from gi.repository import Gdk`

Comment: I will add it to ubiquity first & only then award bounty.

Comment: Can this be done for inline toolbar only?

Comment: You loose brownie points for not being pep8 nor python3 compliant

Comment: Updated for Python3. It should now only apply to inline toolbars. What's the pep8 issue? Line length?

Comment: all good. now the issue is that the border is still there & still takes up space. Let me post a screenshot.

Comment: adding border-width: 0px and padding: 0px made it the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
toolbar_css = ".inline-toolbar { background: alpha (@base_color, 0.0); border-color: transparent; }"
css_provider.load_from_data(toolbar_css.encode('UTF-8'))
win_style_context.add_provider(css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```